# Only one worker working in Multithread producer consumer problem

Tags: c

I am working on a consumer producer problem using only condition variables.
there should be 1 producer, 3 consumers, buffer size of 2 and 5 tasks for consumers to be done.
However, the result seems to have only 1 consumer working
Also, the other consumers cannot enter the pthread_join.....
I have been stuck here for days and I need your help!!! thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t empty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, fill= PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int buffer_size;
int *buffer;
int fill_ptr = 0;                                   //the place next producer should put place task
int use_ptr = 0;
int count = 0;                                      //number of task on the buffer
int work_done=0;
int consumers=0;
int loops =0;

typedef struct {
    int a;
}con_id;

void put(int value){
    buffer[fill_ptr]=value;
    fill_ptr = (fill_ptr+1)%buffer_size;                    //update fill pointer
    count ++;
}

int get(){
    int tmp = buffer[use_ptr];
    use_ptr = (use_ptr + 1)%buffer_size;
    count --;
    work_done++;
    return tmp;
}


void *producer(void *args){                 //producer

    for(int i = 0; i<loops ;i++){                       //loops???
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(count == buffer_size)                         //if the buffer is full
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex);      //wait until empty signal is broadcasted
        printf("I am producer: I now put task\n");
        put(i);
        printf("buffer[]: [");
        for(int j=0;j<buffer_size;j++){
            printf(" %d ,", buffer[j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");                                      //else rest code: place task
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&fill);                  //broadcast fill signal??????????
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    printf("I am producer: I quit now\n");
}

void *consumer(void *arg){
    con_id *consumer_id = malloc(sizeof(con_id));
    consumer_id->a = *((int *)arg);
    for (int i=0; i<loops;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(count ==0){                           //if the buffer is empty
            pthread_cond_wait(&fill, &mutex);
        }                       
        //printf("I am consumer:%d, I now get task\n", i);//else rest code:get task 
        int tmp = get();                            //tmp?
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&empty);             //broadcast empty signal????????
        printf("buffer[use_ptr]: %d\n", tmp);       
        int tmp2= *((int *)arg);            //tmp?
        printf("I am consumer:%d, I have done a task\n", tmp2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);               
    }

    return (void*) consumer_id;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    buffer_size = 2;
    loops = 5;
    consumers = 3;



    buffer = malloc(sizeof(int)*buffer_size);           //allocate space for the buffer

    pthread_t prods, cons[consumers];                   //declare producer and consumers threads

    pthread_create(&prods, NULL, producer, NULL);       //create producers thread

    for (int i = 0; i < consumers; i++){
        int *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
        *arg = i;
        pthread_create(&cons[i], NULL,consumer, arg);   // create consumer threads

    }

    pthread_join(prods, NULL);                          //wait for all threads to finish
    printf("producer ended\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < consumers+1; i++){
        printf(" waiting for consumers to end\n");
        con_id *consumer_id;
        pthread_join(cons[i], (void**) &consumer_id);
        printf("joined %d\n", consumer_id->a);
    }



    printf("everything fucking done!");
    return 0;
}
```

RESULTS:

```
I am producer: I now put task
buffer[]: [ 0 , 0 ,]
I am producer: I now put task
buffer[]: [ 0 , 1 ,]
buffer[use_ptr]: 0
I am consumer:2, I have done a task
buffer[use_ptr]: 1
I am consumer:2, I have done a task
I am producer: I now put task
buffer[]: [ 2 , 1 ,]
I am producer: I now put task
buffer[]: [ 2 , 3 ,]
buffer[use_ptr]: 2
I am consumer:2, I have done a task
buffer[use_ptr]: 3
I am consumer:2, I have done a task
I am producer: I now put task
buffer[]: [ 4 , 3 ,]
I am producer: I quit now
producer ended
 waiting for consumers to end
buffer[use_ptr]: 4
I am consumer:2, I have done a task
```

the program cannot end, and I have to use Ctrl-C to kill it

Comment: I have not had the time to analyse the whole thing but a quick look raised a couple of oddities. I think you are having a inverse priority problem adn the producer finishes before all the consumers start. So you should start the consumers before you start the producer and have a small delay so the consumers start. Also, the retval parameter of pthread_join() is the parameter given to pthread_exit(), which is the right way to exit a thread instead relying on the return terminate it.

Comment: Consider adding some delay to the consumer to make them do some 'work'. It will allow you to test the code with 'stress'